# combining multiple arrays. debugging xcode swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, debugging

I am in the process of building a flashcard app. I have attached my code below. When the code below runs the user should be able to swipe left and right through an array of Cards(each card contains an image coupled with a sound. There are two arrays of Cards called firstList and secondList). When an image is tapped, the sound it is coupled with should play. I am not getting an issue playing the sound or swiping through a single list. However, I am getting an error when I try to combine and swipe through "firstList" and "secondList". One of the errors I cannot seem to figure out is "type of expression is ambiguous without more context".  please see the code and the error below

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {

var imageIndex: Int = 0
@IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

struct List {
    let words: [Card] /*Create array of cards*/
    var active: Bool
}



let firstList:[Card] = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "lake")!, soundUrl: "lake"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "river")!, soundUrl: "river"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "ocean")!, soundUrl: "ocean")
]

let secondList:[Card] = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "alligator")!, soundUrl: "alligator"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "apple")!, soundUrl: "apple"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "grape")!, soundUrl: "grape")
]

override func viewDidLoad() {


    var imageList: [String] {
        let list1 = List(words:firstList, active: true)
        let list2 = List(words:secondList, active: true)

        let wordLists = [list1, list2]

        let active = wordLists.reduce([]) { (result:[String], list:List) in
            if list.active {
                return result + list.words

            } else {
                return result
            }
        }

        return active

    }

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


    imgPhoto.image = (wordLists)[0]; ).image

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}


func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    itemList[imageIndex].playSound()
    // Your action
}
func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
            print("User swiped right")

            // decrease index first

            imageIndex -= 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex < 0 {

                imageIndex = itemList.count - 1

            }

            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("User swiped Left")

            // increase index first

            imageIndex += 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex > itemList.count - 1 {

                imageIndex = 0

            }

            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
        default:


            break //stops the code/codes nothing.
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]

The class that contains the information for each "Card" is below

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

class Card: NSObject
{
var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String


init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
}
 func playSound()

{ print("play")
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    print("hhh")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

`result + list.words`

`result` is a `[String]` and `list.words` is a `[Card]`. What are you trying to accomplish with this line?

**Second problem:**

`imgPhoto.image = (wordLists)[0]; ).image`

`wordLists` is a `[List]`, each of which contains `[Card]` as the property `words`

It looks like you're trying to grab an image from one of the cards in one of the lists but it's unclear which card you are trying to grab. An example of grabbing the image from the first card from the first list would be:

`imgPhoto.image = wordLists[0].words[0].image`

**Third problem:**

You're trying to refer to a variable called `itemList` that doesn't seem to exist. It is not declared anywhere in the code you listed, but I suspect it is meant to a property of that class.

Comment: if you see that there is the "firstList" and "secondList" each contains 3 cards so there is 6 cards in total.  When the app runs I want to beable to swipe left and right through the 6 cards.  I tried to combine the "firstList" and "secondList" with the result + list.words but evidently that did not work.  could you offer a solution to fix this?

Comment: The issue is as I explained above, you are trying to concatenate 2 different kinds of things. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to use the `soundUrl` property? What would you expect `results` to contain after that code runs?

Comment: so as you can see in the override func where I state let list1... let list2... I set each one to active(I have a settings page to control each list) so result is a compilation of all of the active lists. if the list is not active (if I turn off the list in the settings page) then that list will not be passed to result.  I changed the result[String] to result[any] and that cleared up some of the errors but there are still remaining issues.